# How to manipulate date in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having problem with manipulation of dates. I have a variable *savedTime* variable in localstorage wich contains this date:

```
Wed Aug 31 2016 16:31:30 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)
```

I need add 1 hour for this variable *savedTime* to check if passed 1 hour:

```
var savedTime = new Date(savedTime); //converts string to date object
var checkExpired = savedTime.setHours(savedTime.getHours() + 1); //add 1 hour to savedTime
```

But on trying add 1 hour to this variable converting the string in a object, this (*savedTime*) returns:

```
1472675490000
```

What i expected is the string with + 1 hour:

```
Wed Aug 31 2016 17:31:30 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)
```

And compare dates to check if passed 1 hour

```
var currentDate = new Date();
if(currentDate > checkExpired) {
    //passed 1 hour
}
```

Comment: Do you want to be able to compare the dates or be able to format the number you got from the date?

Comment: Not certain what issue is?

Comment: You seem to be getting exactly what you want, but dates in javascript are in milliseconds, only the string representation is in the expected format ?

Comment: You are comparing `1472675490000` with `26 Wed Aug 31 2016 22:01:11 GMT+0100 (BST)` which cant be compared to be greater than

Comment: I updated the question to explain better

Comment: When calling  `savedTime.setHours(...)` its modifying the `Date` instance referenced by `savedTime` but _returning_ the new value in ms since unix epoch. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours#Return_value
This seems to have convoluted the question and answers.
Comparison between `Date` instances is perfectly valid and arguably clearer than having to remember `setHours` automagically returns number of milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.getTime()`

```
if(currentDate.getTime() > checkExpired) {
    //passed 1 hour
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`instance.setHours()` manipulates the instance. So you can do

```
d = new Date('Wed Aug 31 2016 16:31:30 GMT-0300');
d.setHours(d.getHours() + 1);
```

Now `d` contains the new datetime.

Answer (score 2):

`setHours` will manipulate the current object and return it's new value. Instead of using the return value, just continue to use the object.

```
var savedTime = new Date(savedTime); //converts string to date object
savedTime.setHours(savedTime.getHours() + 1); //add 1 hour to the savedTime

if (currentDate > savedTime) {
    //passed 1 hour
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the value back in milliseconds from the 'epoch date' which is January first 1970.

If you want this in the correct format, you will need to parse this information out into that with some math / other Date object functions.

Here is the documentation to do that, it's very straightforward:

[JS Date Formatting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)